# How to call a function periodically in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

Is it possible to call a function periodically in C++ with Qt function ?
And how to stop the timed function after it is set to be called periodically ?

Comment: To the duplicate flaggers: The OP is specifically asking for a Qt solution, the "duplicate" answer is a generic C++ one - they are not the same which is why the accepted answer is not the same.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you are using qt, you can you QTimer which by default creates a repetitive timer.

There is an example in the documentation (shown below) and an example (Analog Clock).

```
QTimer *timer = new QTimer(this);
connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(update()));
timer->start(1000);
```

Comment: Is there actually a reason why the `QTimer` is created as a pointer via `new`? Couldn't I use `QTimer timer(this);`?

Comment: In this example the timer is created in the constructor. If you used a local variable, `timer` would go out of scope, at the end of construction and the timer would be destroyed and so not run

Comment: Oh...even when the `QTimer` is a member of the class?

Comment: No, if it's a member it won't go out of scope and so will work ok.

Comment: So, if `QTimer` is a member of the class: Would I declare it as an object `QTimer` or a reference `QTimer&`? The need to use a pointer declaration `QTimer*` would only arise if I can't/don't want to initialize it in the initializer list of the class' constructor?

Comment: `QTimer(this)` is setting the parent to `this`, but you could use the default constructor and then use `setParent()` to set the timer, so do it however you like.

Comment: I meant, when `QTimer` is a member of the class, there is no reason to declare `QTimer*` unless I need to re-assign another instance of `QTimer` at a later point or if I don't want to instantiate the `QTimer` in the constructor, correct?

Comment: But how do you `delete timer` once you're out of the scope? Looks like a memory leak

Comment: In the example there is a single instance which will be cleared up when the program exits. If you were creating and deleting multiple instances of a class using the timer, you would make the timer a member and delete it in the destructor.

Comment: @LCsa  & parkydr THANKS YOU!!!!!!!!, Your 1st comment made me understand the fault with what I was struggling for 6hours. Nothing related to Timers though. Wonderful coincidence I saw this.

Answer (score 2):

One possibility would be to use a `QTimer` `timeout` signal and a `QObject` slot. Connect the two and `start()` the timer.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtimer.html#timeout

To stop the timer, call `stop()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [QTimer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtimer.html) class.

Just declare a `QTimer` with the desired time interval, wrap your function in a `QObject` as a slot, and connect the `QTimer`'s `timeout()` signal to the slot you just declared.

Then, when the condition for stopping calling the function  is met, just call `QTimer::stop()`.

Answer (score 1):

As people have said in answers before me, you can use the timeout() signal to trigger a function to run.

If you want to stop the timer at some point, you can connect to the stop() slot, or call it directly yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Make a function that uses timer functionallity or a while loop that just waits for 100 ms and when your function meets the requirement just break. You could quite easy found a solution on this one if you just made a search among all the other questions that has been posted here.