# Interval between every loop iteration

Tags: c++, loops, qt, oop, timer

I have a Qt project in which I get a directory path as input and based on some conditions generate a certain number of images and save those images later in the same directory path. What's expected is to be able to manipulate the time it takes for the program to generate these result images in a way, that after every generated image, there will be a certain interval (for example 5 seconds/5000 milliseconds). So:

image1.jpg
[5 seconds later]
image2.jpg
[5 seconds later]
image3.jpg
and so on.

These result images are initially saved inside a QVector, and are iterated through using a for loop, and are then saved in the directory path one by one. So I don't want the implementation of the interval ruin the structure of the code.

Here's my snippet where I save the result images one by one in the path using a for loop:

```
//save images

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

QObject::connect(ui->buttonRender, &QAbstractButton::clicked, this, [this]() { //Connection for when buttonRender is clicked
        JsonParser *jsonParserInstance = new JsonParser(_dirPath, _originalPath);

        QVector<QImage> framedPics = jsonParserInstance->returnRes(); //Create an instance of class JsonParser

        QImage img;
        img.fill(Qt::black);

        for(int i=0; i<framedPics.length(); ++i) { //Iterate through every result image (single and at last the final image)
            img = framedPics[i];
            QString savePath;
            if(i == framedPics.length()-1) savePath = "\\Ergebnis_Final.jpg"; //For the last image that contains several ROIs at the same time
            else savePath = QStringLiteral("\\Ergebnis_%1.jpg").arg(i+1);
            img.save(_dirPath+savePath); //Absolute path where the result image will be saved
        }
});
```

So basically I want the interval only affect this part of my code, and NOT cause a delay on the whole proccess of my project. I have read about QTimeLine and QTimer, but I don't understand how I can apply an interval to this specific action in my code. I really appreciate any help.

Note that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16786109/how-to-call-a-function-periodically-in-qt) still does not answer my question, because in my snippet the loop is in a lambda function as a slot for when a button is clicked. So technically I am already having a connection and the slot is a lambda function.

Comment: [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)? Can you explain why you care about the exact time when the images are stored, rather than storing them as soon as it can be done?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to call a function periodically in Qt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16786109/how-to-call-a-function-periodically-in-qt) In your case `connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(saveImage()));` - where save image will take consecutive img from vector (if exists).

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai it's the customer requirement, does not make sense to me either but that's what's required :D

Comment: create a Qthread, and have the timer running in it so that it won't affect your app. (not block your main application while saving to disk).

Comment: @pptaszni Your solution is a connect from timer to a method called saveImage() that does what my snippet does, but the point is, in my snippet the loop is in a lambda function as a slot for when a button is clicked. So technically I am already having a connection, how can I write the line you provided when the slot is a lambda function? :)

Comment: Now I don't understand what you are asking about. Qt connection + lambda: this you already know how, as can be seen in your example. Button click + some kind of image generation and storing them in `QVector`: this you also know how to do. `QTimer` executing some function periodically: this is shown in the linked question. So, what is the remaining problem? Just implement the logic that you need.